# JMenuBar not showing when it should

Tags: java, swing, jmenubar

Everything seems right, but the menubar doesn't show up, I might just be missing something.

This frame gets called from the main class with a simple `new AffmView();`. Could that cause this problem?

```
public class AffmView extends JFrame {

public AffmView() {
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AffmView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
     this.setSize(700, 500);
    this.setTitle("'s Factorio Mod Manager");
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu packsMenu = new JMenu("Modpacks");
    JMenuItem newPackMI = new JMenuItem("New Pack");
    packsMenu.add(newPackMI);
    menubar.add(packsMenu);
    this.setJMenuBar(menubar);

    this.rootPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //snipped so that StackOverflow wont make me write an essay, but its 
    //just some basic swing

    this.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

I have confirmed that none of the snipped parts cause the issue.

Comment: don't know why but if you remove `this.rootPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());` it works .may be need to call `this.rootPane.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());` not sure

Comment: No need to involve the root pane at all. Just use `setLayout( new GridBagLayout() );`

Comment: @FastSnail Derp... It draws the menubar on the rootpane.. which I am messing with. Could you make an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @PrivateAlpha as camickr said use `setLayout( new GridBagLayout() );` i have never used rootpane like this

Comment: @FastSnail yeah, I see now it really wasn't necessary to do it that way. Thanks a ton for the help!

Comment: Not only is it not necessary, it's guaranteed to mess you up. Study the tutorials to see what the root pane is responsible for and why you shouldn't mess with it like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @FastSnail and @camickr in the comments, the issue lies with the usage of `this.rootPane`.

getContentPane() should have been used instead.